# How do I convert an int into 5-bit 2s complement in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have -9 as an integer, how would I convert this into a 5 bit 2s complement integer in C? Essentially getting 10111?

What my current code looks like:

```
char src2[3] = "-9";
int int_src2 = atoi(src2);
int_src2 = int_src2 & 31;
```

My immediate thoughts are int_src2 is 8388112 when set is 16 after the AND operation - whereas I wanted 10111

Comment: should the result be a string?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to do that ? XY problem probably spotted here.

Comment: @JulienPalard, for immediate addressing in LC3.

Comment: @ForeverLearning ahh so it's for a school exercice ? ^-^

Comment: I think `x & ((1<<5)-1)` is good enough.

Comment: @JulienPalard, yes. I have also added my current working.

Comment: Please support "int_src2 is 8388112"?

Comment: @barakmanos - your solution works!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of bitfields and unions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int bit1:1;
    unsigned int bit2:1;
    unsigned int bit3:1;
    unsigned int bit4:1;
    unsigned int bit5:1;
} five;

typedef union {five f; int i;} u;

int main() {
    u test;
    test.i = -9;
    printf("%u%u%u%u%u\n",test.f.bit5,test.f.bit4,test.f.bit3,test.f.bit2,test.f.bit1);
    return 0;
}
```

live example: https://ideone.com/ow0Bl6

Comment: Whould not this typically be dependent on underlying architecture (big-endian, little-endian, and int size) ?

Comment: Also this looks like C++ to me (Yet I'm a C89 developer, I'm not acustomed to recent additions to C as I never touch them).

Comment: @JulienPalard this can definitely be depending on the endianess, I don't know about the int-size. I don't claim platform independence... it should be C, however I am rather a C++ developer :)

Comment: My C compiler don't want it ^^ My c++ does.

Comment: @JulienPalard please try the updated version, gcc compiles it for me

Comment: I use gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, from October 2014, not something that I can  consider old ^^